# How to position a button using X and Y coordinates in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to position a button at place having certain pixels distance from left and top. I have the exact position in pixels of where to place the button. But, how can I do so?

Comment: Look in to Absolute layout for xamarin forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Absolute layout

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/

Another option is create view renderer which implement this funcionality in native part.